# Using Delphi, Do I need to uninstall, build, install a package which source code has changed after it was installed?

Tags: delphi, installation, build, package, uninstallation

I am currently uninstalling the ".bpl" component package, changing to source code, building it and installing it.

I'm thinking I'm doing it the logical way, but I wonder if I'm doing a unnecessary step or is there a faster way to do this while debugging my component?

Comment: If you are changing any code in an `interface` or `requires` section, then yes, do a full uninstall/re-install. Otherwise no, you should not need to do that if all you are doing is `implementation` changes.

Comment: You don't have to uninstall, build and then reinstall. Open the .dpk file, then open the source and make your edits. When you've saved your changes, right-click the package name in the Project Manager and choose *Install* from the pop-up menu, and the IDE will take care of all of that for you in a single step.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to uninstall a package before making any changes. I've worked on plenty packages in my time, and never had a need to do so. The only situation where it's necessary would be if you have changed its name, or its location. Otherwise, just be sure to build/install it again after any edits.

Comment: You don't have to build/install. You can just install after the edit. The IDE is smart enough to know it needs to be built first.

Comment: @KenWhite Indeed. I meant "build/install" as in whatever's necessary. Sometimes you have a runtime library which has no install...